# Are there any stats about tennis matches?

Tags: dataset, datasource

Stats about:

```
 - % first serve 
 - % second serve
 - winners
 - faults
 - double faults
 - longest rallys (number of shots) 
 - average rallys (number of shots) 
 - serve max speed
 - serve average speed
```

Even better if it will be by set/game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found some data sources:

- [Tennisabstract](http://www.tennisabstract.com/)
  regularly manually updated resource. For now there is detailed stats for more than 3000 single matches. Everybody can join.
- [ATPWorldTour](http://www.atpworldtour.com/) stats by season, player career. Also found [API](https://github.com/danielkorzekwa/atpworldtour-api)